# Loading different files using OWL API

Tags: owl, owl-api

I am using OWL API to load different files and merge into one for reasoning. I have one file describing the ontology and several files with individuals. Every individual has foaf properties, e.g., foaf:title, when I print the axioms  it shows

'AnnotationAssertion(http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/title...'

and reasoning does not work. If I add 
<'owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/title'/> 
into the individual file than title loads as

'DataPropertyAssertion(http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/title...' and reasoning works.

In the FOAF ontology is says that it is a data property, but loading it did not work either. I am using OWLOntologyMerger to merge the ontologies.

And I cannot add that into every file. Is there a way to do it programmatically or any way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use owl:imports from each file to import the base ontology, or foaf.
The problem here is that the owl api needs the declaration to be available either in the file or in the imported ontologies. It is not possible to parse rdf/XML unambiguously otherwise.

Comment: If I use owl:imports into each file it works. Can I import programmatically into every ontology when I load it to the manager or apply it after I load all the files? I don't want to edit all the files.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the declarations need to be therevay parse time. It should be possible to work directly with the parsers to avoid modifying the files but I've never tried it before.